# Martingale-cotype vs cotype on super-reflexive spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm have difficultly nailing down the direction of some implications.  For $2 \leq q < \infty$, there are (at least) two ways to say that a Banach space $B$ has "cotype $q$".

- $B$ has **cotype** q.
- $B$ is isomorphic to a $q$-**uniformly convex Banach space**, i.e. a uniformly convex Banach space with a "power type" modulus of uniform convexity  $\delta(\varepsilon) = C \varepsilon^q$.  ($B$ is said to have **martingale cotype** q.  The name comes from a [characterization by Pisier involving martingales](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760337).)

I know the following:

1. Every $q$-uniformly convex Banach space (and any space isomorphic to it) has cotype $q$.
2. There are nonreflexive spaces, e.g. $L^1$ and $\ell^1$, with cotype $2$.  Since they are nonreflexive they are not isomorphic to a uniformly convex space.
3. The super-reflexive spaces are exactly those isomorphic to uniformly convex spaces, which in turn are all isomorphic to $q$-uniformly convex spaces.

However, I can't seem to find the answer to the following.

> If a space is **super-reflexive** and of cotype $q$, is it isomorphic to a $q$-uniformly convex space?

If not, is there a nice class of spaces where these two notions of cotype agree?

---

**Update 1:** I have some partial answers of spaces for which the notions agree (but not yet a general answer to my question).

- **UMD spaces**. (see Cédric's answer).
- **Banach lattices of type $p>1$** (which includes the super-reflexive Banach lattices).  I found a pair of interdependence diagrams on pp. 100, 101 of Lindenstrass and Tzafriri's "Classical Banach Spaces II" (these are some of the best math diagrams I have seen).  On a Banach lattice, the modulus of convexity is of power type $q$ for an equivalent norm if and only if is of cotype $q$ and there is an upper estimate $p>1$. Following the diagram, "upper estimate" can be replaced with "type".

**Update 2:** On the bottom of p. 78 of Lindenstrass and Tzafriri's "Classical Banach Spaces II" my main question is listed as an open problem.  So I guess my question becomes, has it been solved yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer this with what I've found:

---

(1) The answer to my main question is that it is not true.  In this [document of Pisier's](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~tt249057/other/figel_fulltext.pdf), he states

> It is possible to find a uniformly convex space $B$ for which the index of type $p(B)$ differs from the corresponding index for the $M$-type. Similarly for the cotype. See [P4] for details.

The reference [P4] is

> G. PISIER, Un exempte concernant la super-réflexivité.  Annexe no. 2.  Séminaire Maurey-Schwartz 1974-75. Ecole Polytechnique. Paris.

which I can't seem to find, so I'll have to take his word for it.

---

(2) As I added to my original post, it seems the two best cases where they agree are UMD spaces (thanks Cédric) and Banach lattices of type $p>1$.

Comment: You can find the Pisier's paper here:

http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SAF_1974-1975____A27_0

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Suppose that $X$ has UMD (hence super-refexive). It seems to me that the following equivalence is classical.

Then $X$ is of cotype $q$ if and only if $X$ is $q$-uniformly convex.

Comment: Thanks.  I assume you mean to say "$X$ is isomorphic to a $q$-uniformly convex space".  (It seems that $\mathsf{UMD}$ is preserved under isomorphisms, where as uniform convexity is not.  That is of course if we are using the same definition of $q$-uniformly convex.)  Also, I'm still hoping for an answer to my main question, but maybe $\mathsf{UMD}$ is the best known.

Comment: Undoubtedly, you must look at the Bourgain's exemple of supereflexive space failing UMD and see...

Comment: Cédric, I found the article, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02384306, but I am not sure I understand your comment.  Are you saying if I understood this example, I might be able to answer my question?

Comment: My feeling is that the answer is false and that you need to study the exemples of super-reflexive spaces which are not UMD. Maybe, one of them is a counter-example to your question. See the recent paper http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1112.0739 for information on all known counter-examples.